# Correct Typography: Should Parentheses have same Height as Exponent Numbers or not?

Tags: typography, brackets, units, parentheses, siunits

Which behavior has the correct typography:

Should parentheses/brackets have the same height as exponent numbers or not?

---

**Example no. 1:**

`[ \si{\square\meter} ]`

[image: Screenshot of first example]

---

**Example no. 2:**

`\left[ \si{\square\meter} \right]`

Alternative replaced by:

`\big[ \si{\square\meter} \big]`

[image: Screenshot of second example]

---

I am not sure about which one of those has the correct typographic way on how to use the parentheses...

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks! As far as I understood I should stop using `\left[ ... \right]` at all. But: Should I use `\biggl` instead, or do the standard parentheses `[` have the correct size already (even if the exponents seem higher)?

Comment: Longer answer: parentheses need not end up above exponents.

Comment: @egreg: Awesome, thanks a lot for your expertise! May you want to post this as an answer?

Comment: That would need a lot of research; maybe later or tomorrow. But I'm not sure it is strictly a TeX question.

Comment: It clearly is not. @Dave While I am going with egreg's opinion, I want to make clear that it is an opinion only. Both your examples are absolutely visually and mathematical understandable and I do not know any technical standard defining such things. So they are both correct. If you find the second one more pleasing, use it (but maybe your readers won't...)

Comment: BUT: Please do not put your units in square brackets. That is visually disturbing and technically (even talking about common standards) wrong. Correct would be `$[A]=\si{\square\meter}$` or `$A$ in \si{\square\meter}` or `Area: $A/\si{\square\meter}$` or somthing alike.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi This probably heavily depends on the area of study. For axis labels or column headings in tables, this notation is pretty much standard in astronomy and astroparticle physics

Comment: @samcarter well, if you want to stick to SI, which is really standard in any field, then it is just wrong. But I believe that discussion is somewhere around this page already. Units are set upright and symbols italic. If that is not enough for tables and graphs then you can have a look on the other proposals in my prior post.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: Thanks for your comments! I want to put the unit on the right side of an equation, for example like that: `A = B + C    \qquad [\si{\square\meter}]` - that should be fine I think?

Comment: @Dave no, my argumentation is that those brackets are always wrong. Just add "in m" and you are just fine. Compromise would be "(m)". Just make sure not to set the m italic (will not happen with `siunitx`.)

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: Ah thank you, I understand! In general I always put the units as `\si{unit}`, so there is no danger to write it italic. I am just not sure about the reason why those brackets are not allowed? At least in Europe this seems to be common sense?

Comment: https://www.bipm.org/utils/common/pdf/si-brochure-draft-2016.pdf The number of a value `Q` is defined by the value of Q defined as `{Q}` multiplied by the unit of Q defined as `[Q]`. That means `Q={Q}[Q] \hat [Q]=\si{unit}`. That is the official SI definition of square brackets (the above link is just a draft, but I promise you, it is in older documents as well). The common sense in Europe is a mistake and it will become more as some famous tools are displaying units in the wrong manner.

Comment: The author of `siunitx` briefly treats that in his manual: "Placing the unit in square brackets is common but mathematically poor."

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: Oh, good to know that! :-) Well, inside equations I never put the units in brackets. I only put them in brackets if the equation does NOT contain units and I want to tell the reader which unit the result of the equation has.